# Sum all numbers depending on neighbours dates

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have such table

```
---------------------------------
A    B            C    D
---------------------------------
10   20.09.2019   5    12.10.2019
7    11.10.2019   2     2.11.2019
3    11.09.2019   8     3.10.2019
12   14.09.2019   11   18.09.2019
```

Each number has a date in the cell to its right.
I'm trying to SUM all numbers which have a MONTH=9

```
=arrayformula(SUMIF(MONTH(A1:D4);9;ISEVEN(COLUMN(A1:D4))))
```

So the Result must be 10+3+12+11=36

Comment: How many pairs of Value,Date columns do you have? Is it just for columns A-D or are there many more columns?

Comment: Don't post the [same question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/136898/sum-all-numbers-which-have-right-month-in-date-in-a-neighbour-cell) twice.

Comment: There are more then 50 of columns of Values and Data.

Answer (score 1):

My initial suggestion is to use the following formula in a cell beneath all of the rows in the table

```
=ARRAYFORUMLA(SUMIF(MONTH(B1:B4),9,A1:A4))
```

Then from that cell, drag the formula across all columns in the table.
[image: Google Sheets Conditional Month Formula]

Then you can sum the resulting row to get the final sum of all columns.

This requires a few more steps and I am not well-versed enough in Google Sheets formulas to put this into one formula for now, but at least this is a starting point.

Comment: Also I'm from the US so ignore the format of the date in this example.

Comment: My mistake I didn't mention that I have more then 50 columns of such Values and Dates.

Comment: @OlegSolomatin this solution will still work for the case of many columns. Just be sure to drag the formula across all columns.

Answer (score 0):

*Migrating my answer here after the original post on Web Applications was deleted.*

Use this:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(MONTH(B1:B4), 9, A1:A4)+SUMIF(MONTH(D1:D4), 9, C1:C4))`

The result of your example should be 36 by the way. You accidentally added the number of days of one of the dates to the total.

You don't need to create extra cells for this. `MONTH` only takes on range but you can repeat add multiple `SUMIF` results together depending on the number of columns you want to include in the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for a hint! But what if I have more then 50 columns and I need to find SUM all values which have a MONTH=9 in the right cell.